# Does the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit assure that the left-hand limit and right-hand limit should be the same?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know that the left-hand limit and right-hand limit should be the same if the limit exists. But the $x$ in the definition is an element of the domain of the function $f$, so here's the question: If function $f$ is defined only for $x \ge 0$, then can we say that the limit for $x = 0$ exists for function $f$? It is trivial for the right-hand limit, but I would like to know if we can say this right-hand limit as "the limit" when $x$ goes to $0$.

According to the epsilon delta definition, it seems to hold since $x$ cannot be smaller than $0$, and thus the right-hand limit would become the limit itself.

Comment: Well as I see, when you write $x\to 0$ you don't specify how exactly $x$ approaches $0$. Since $x$ can approach $0$ from both the left and right side, but $f(x)$ is not defined on $0>x$, I'd say that $f$ has a right-hand side limit at $0$ but not a limit - but I believe those are only semantics and I might be wrong.

Comment: If a function $f$ is only defined for $x\geq 0$, then it is correct that the limit is the same as the right-hand limit. The left hand limit at $0$ is a bit more dodgy though. The left hand limit would be a number $L$, such that 
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \: \exists \delta > 0 \: \forall x \geq 0 \: : \quad x \in (-\delta,0) \Rightarrow |f(x)-L| < \epsilon,$$
which is actually true for all $L$, since $x\in (-\delta,0)$ would be false for all $x\geq 0$.   One way of salvaging the definition is to leave the left-hand limit undefined, when the function is not defined to the left.